# Treatment of 'empty' values

Tags: r

I am importing a csv file into R using the `sqldf`-package. I have several missing values for both numeric and string variables. I notice that missing values are left empty in the dataframe (as opposed to being filled with NA or something else). I want to replace the missing values with an user defined value. Obviously, a function like `is.na()` will not work in this case.

Toy dataframe with three columns:

```
A  B  C  
3  4  
2  4  6   
34 23 43   
2  5
```

I want:

```
A  B  C  
3  4  NA  
2  4  6   
34 23 43   
2  5  NA
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `read.csv.sql` in `sqldf` with the default `sqlite` database it is producing a factor column for C so

(1) just convert the values to numeric using `as.numeric(as.character(...))` like this:

```
> Lines <- "A,B,C
+ 3,4,
+ 2,4,6
+ 34,23,43
+ 2,5,
+ "
> cat(Lines, file = "stest.csv")
> library(sqldf)
> DF <- read.csv.sql("stest.csv")
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  3 2 34 2
 $ B: int  4 4 23 5
 $ C: Factor w/ 3 levels "","43","6": 1 3 2 1
> DF$C <- as.numeric(as.character(DF$C))
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  3 2 34 2
 $ B: int  4 4 23 5
 $ C: num  NA 6 43 NA
```

(2) or if we use `sqldf(..., method = "raw")` then we can just use `as.numeric`:

```
> DF <- read.csv.sql("stest.csv", method = "raw")
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  3 2 34 2
 $ B: int  4 4 23 5
 $ C: chr  "" "6" "43" ""
> DF$C <- as.numeric(DF$C)
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  3 2 34 2
 $ B: int  4 4 23 5
 $ C: num  NA 6 43 NA
```

(3)  If its feasible for you to use `read.csv` then we do get `NA` filling right off:

```
> str(read.csv("stest.csv"))
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  3 2 34 2
 $ B: int  4 4 23 5
 $ C: int  NA 6 43 NA
```